# What is the word for a slime monster's movement?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

A slime monster like The Blob makes what movement? Slither is too snake like. I've thought of words like "gloop" and "drip", but it doesn't convey movement.

Comment: The one collocation I could find is *slide* which is not at all that impressive!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They *ooze*, in the sense given [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3aooze):

> The sluggish flow of a fluid.

or [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ooze)

> to move or pass slowly or gradually, as if through a small opening or passage:

In fact, recent versions of D&D have classified [such monsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ooze_%28Dungeons_%26_Dragons%29) as "oozes".

I might also describe such a motion as *creeping*, assuming that it was moving slowly.  If the monster were to be moving more rapidly, than *flowing* might be appropriate.  Glancing at some articles about slime molds, it seems the term *streaming* is used to describe their peculiar type of motion.

Comment: *Ooze* and *seep* are nearly synonymous. However, try finding some usage examples, because I am a bit unconvinced. I think both the words related to movement 'through' something or such.

Comment: ooze is most certainly the term here. maybe you can verb the noun "slime" as well, like "The Blob slimed along." I wouldn't mind, though others might...

Comment: No, no, "slime" is a transitive verb, describing what happens when the monster in motion collides with you. See Ghostbusters. :)

Comment: @Kris Ooze is appropriate here because a "slime monster" tends to move *as if* it were oozing out of an opening.  Imagine the motion of pus across your skin as it oozes out of a sore; that's the connotation we want in this context.  I already provided a link that attests to this more general sense.

Comment: *seep* is what happens when a liquid slowly suffuses into a porous surface. *ooze* is what slime does.

Comment: @KitFox Good point.

Comment: Watch [the trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkOfeSNsWpM) and hear the announcer say "very soon, the menace will be '**oozing**' into this theater". **Ooze** is the best & maybe the only acceptable answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a web page that tells you how [snails](http://animals.about.com/od/mollusks/ig/World-of-Snails/Snail-5.htm) move, and another that tells you how [slugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug) move. Think of a "slime monster" as a giant snail or slug, both of which are little slime monsters. Because they both create "rhythmic waves of muscular contraction on the underside of [their] foot", you can say that they *undulate*.

This kind of question can easily be answered with a little bit of searching. First, ask the question: "How do snails move?" Then put the question into a browser's search window. The use a thesaurus to find synonyms for, in this case, *[wave](http://thesaurus.com/browse/wave?s=t)*, and you'll find *undulation*. Then go find the verb *[undulate](http://thesaurus.com/browse/undulate?s=t)* in the the thesaurus

Comment: The Blob was more an amoebic entity than a snail or slug; undulate is probably the wrong word there.

Comment: @starwed: I don't remember the movie. I just took my cue from the word "slime". Actually, if you watch the trailer for _The Blob_, you'll hear the announcer say that "very soon, the menace will be '**oozing**' into this theater", so your answer is correct. The movie makers thought that it "oozed".